# Android - Email popup for user feedback? Honeycomb

Tags: android, dialog

I am making a Honeycomb optimized app, and I would like to make a feedback button.

I used to be an iOS developer, and there was this built in Email popup that you could send an email or feedback from without exiting the app to go to the email app.

Is there something like this in Honeycomb? Like some way to send email through a dialog?

That would be greeat, otherwise I am open to any other suggestions of ways I can get user feedback/feature requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built in "popup" but you can use an E-mail intent to start the email client (of the user's choice) with a preset "to" email address:

```
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "THE SUBJECT");
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"youremail@wherever.com"});
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] {"anotheremail@wherever.com"});
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "PRESET TEXT");
      sendIntent.setType(CONTENT_TYPE_EMAIL);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "CHOOSER DIALOG TEXT"));
```

If the user has multiple mail Apps configured, this will open an "open with" dialog where the different Apps will show up, and where the user can choose whichever one he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: It's my own project

I'm developing a Feedback library that does what you want. More info here: http://www.android-feedback.com/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: I though that this was clear ("I'm developing..."). Anyway, I've added a disclaimer! Cheers

Comment: This needs an API key.